# Dynamically sizing absolutely positioned text

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/afrodiameter/pen/OwQmyd

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#head {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 160px;
  min-width: 320px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 160px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -24px;
  font-size: 6em;
}
```

```html
<header id="head">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x160" alt="header image"/>
  <h1> Magro Perimeter</h1>
  </header>
```

In the above Pen I have a `div` that contains both an `<img>` and an `<h1>`. I want the bottom of the `<h1>` to be "locked" to the bottom of the `<img>`.

When the user resizes the browser I want the `font-size` to scale accordingly while the bottom of the `<h1>` stays "locked" to the bottom of the `<img>`.

I thought using `vw` would be the way to go but when resizing the browser the `<h1>` moves vertically and thus does not stay locked to the bottom of the image.

I'd like to accomplish this without JS/jQuery or mixins. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very helpful user on Reddit solved this.

```
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 52%;
  font-size: 6vw;
}
```

Why this works I'm not quite sure. It seems counterintuitive to use `top` as opposed to `bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

are you testing with bottom:0?

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#head {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 160px;
  min-width: 320px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 160px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 6em;
}

<header id="head">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x160" alt="header image"/>
  <h1> Magro Perimeter</h1>
  </header>
```

Comment: I did. Because of how large I want the `<h1>` to be I need to adjust `bottom` to be negative in order to get the text to sit at/on the bottom of `#head`.